# MySQL Group By Hours

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to get a report from my history table by hourly usage. `history` table is;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (
`history_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `created` (`created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I want to group by `HOUR` and `COUNT` all records in a given date range.

```
Hours            |    Usage
------------------------------------
00:00-01:00      |      5
01:00-02:00      |      9
02:00-03:00      |      0 (or NULL)
03:00-04:00      |      20
...
...
...
22:00-23:00      |      11
23:00-00:00      |      1
```

I used a query something like this but it doesn't display all hours.

```
SELECT 

CASE 
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 0 AND 1 THEN '00:00 - 01:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN '01:00 - 02:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN '02:00 - 03:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN '03:00 - 04:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 4 AND 5 THEN '04:00 - 05:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 5 AND 6 THEN '05:00 - 06:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 6 AND 7 THEN '06:00 - 07:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 7 AND 8 THEN '07:00 - 08:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 8 AND 9 THEN '08:00 - 09:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 9 AND 10 THEN '09:00 - 10:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 10 AND 11 THEN '10:00 - 11:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 11 AND 12 THEN '11:00 - 12:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 12 AND 13 THEN '12:00 - 13:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 13 AND 14 THEN '13:00 - 14:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 14 AND 15 THEN '14:00 - 15:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 15 AND 16 THEN '15:00 - 16:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 16 AND 17 THEN '16:00 - 17:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 17 AND 18 THEN '17:00 - 18:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 18 AND 19 THEN '18:00 - 19:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 19 AND 20 THEN '19:00 - 20:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 20 AND 21 THEN '20:00 - 21:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 21 AND 22 THEN '21:00 - 23:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 22 AND 23 THEN '22:00 - 23:00'
  WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 23 AND 24 THEN '23:00 - 00:00'
END AS `Hours`,

COUNT(*) AS `usage`
FROM history
WHERE (created BETWEEN '2012-02-07' AND NOW())
GROUP BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 0 AND 1 THEN 1
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 2
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN 3
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN 4
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 4 AND 5 THEN 5
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 5 AND 6 THEN 6
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 6 AND 7 THEN 7
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 7 AND 8 THEN 8
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 8 AND 9 THEN 9
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 9 AND 10 THEN 10
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 10 AND 11 THEN 11
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 11 AND 12 THEN 12
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 12 AND 13 THEN 13
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 13 AND 14 THEN 14
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 14 AND 15 THEN 15
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 15 AND 16 THEN 16
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 16 AND 17 THEN 17
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 17 AND 18 THEN 18
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 18 AND 19 THEN 19
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 19 AND 20 THEN 20
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 20 AND 21 THEN 21
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 21 AND 22 THEN 22
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 22 AND 23 THEN 23
    WHEN HOUR(created) BETWEEN 23 AND 24 THEN 24
END
```

It displays only if there are any records.

```
Hours            |    Usage
------------------------------------
00:00-01:00      |      5
01:00-02:00      |      9
23:00-00:00      |      1
```

Comment: Create a temporary table with all hours and left join with your actual data.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your existing query can be reduced to:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(HOUR(created), ':00-', HOUR(created)+1, ':00') AS Hours
  ,      COUNT(*) AS `usage`
FROM     history
WHERE    created BETWEEN '2012-02-07' AND NOW()
GROUP BY HOUR(created)
```

To display *every* hour, including those for which there is no data, you need to outer join with a table containing all the hours for which you want data.  You can build such a table in your query using `UNION`:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(Hour, ':00-', Hour+1, ':00') AS Hours
  ,      COUNT(created) AS `usage`
FROM     history
  RIGHT JOIN (
                   SELECT  0 AS Hour
         UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
         UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
         UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
         UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
         UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
         UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
         UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
         UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
  )      AS AllHours ON HOUR(created) = Hour
WHERE    created BETWEEN '2012-02-07' AND NOW() OR created IS NULL
GROUP BY Hour
ORDER BY Hour
```

However, the treatment of groups for which no data exists is really a matter for business logic that's best placed in your data access layer rather than in the database itself: indeed it should be trivial for your application to use a zero value whenever an hour is absent.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying on @eggyal answer, as another good use case would be to display day as well along with hours.

Suppose you need COUNT of records of past 7 days which is of 24 hour each.

```
SELECT
   dayname(date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS Day,
   CONCAT(Hour, ':00-', Hour+1, ':00') AS Hour,
   COUNT(created) AS `usage`
FROM
   history
   RIGHT JOIN
      (
         SELECT  0 AS Hour
         UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
         UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
         UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
         UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
         UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
         UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
         UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
         UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
      )
      AS totalhours
      ON HOUR(created) = HOUR
      AND DATE(created) = date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
      OR created IS NULL
GROUP BY
   Hour
ORDER BY
   Hour;
```

[image: SQL Result]

Modifying this in the business logic of the backend code or in a stored procedure,

```
INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

can yield query results of past 7 days along with the name of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Given a table *Log* with columns *ts* and *value*, the following will give the hourly average for the last 24 hours (assuming each hour has at least one row).

```
SELECT 
    FROM_UNIXTIME( TRUNCATE( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( `ts` )/3600, 0 ) * 3600 ) as h,
    AVG( `value` ) as v,
    COUNT( * ) as q
FROM 
    Log
GROUP BY 
   h
ORDER BY 
   h desc
LIMIT
    24
```

The column *ts* can be a timestamp or datetime column while *value* is anything that AVG() will accept.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Prashanth's response, I was getting a warning about Hour being ambiguous (Percona 5.7). Also, I was not getting the results in the correct order. The following solved these issues for me and is more clear regarding the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses:

```
SELECT
  dayname(date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS Day,
  CONCAT(Hour, ':00-', Hour+1, ':00') AS Hour,
  COUNT(created_at) AS `total`
FROM logtable
RIGHT JOIN
  (
     SELECT  0 AS Hour
     UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
     UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
     UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
     UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
     UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
     UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
     UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
     UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
  )
  AS totalhours
  ON ( HOUR(created_at) = HOUR
  AND DATE(created_at) = date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
  OR created_at IS NULL
GROUP BY
   CONCAT(Hour, ':00-', Hour+1, ':00')
ORDER BY
   totalhours.Hour;
```