# Mysql result hourly data

Tags: mysql, date, time

I'm trying to count entries grouped per hour.
I've found some useful info inform on different sites and here on: [MySQL Group By Hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429611/mysql-group-by-hours)

But the result is not what I've expected.
With the following code I get:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(Hour, ':00-', Hour+1, ':00') AS Hours,
     COUNT(`usage_time`) AS `usage` FROM `usage`
  RIGHT JOIN (
                   SELECT  0 AS Hour
         UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
         UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
         UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
         UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
         UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
         UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
         UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
         UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
  )      AS AllHours ON HOUR(`usage_time`) = Hour

WHERE `usage_function` LIKE 'PlayedWholeSong' AND `usage_date` = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) OR `usage_time` IS NULL
GROUP BY Hour
ORDER BY Hour
```

Result:

```
Hours       usage
2:00-3:00   0
4:00-5:00   6
6:00-7:00   2
8:00-9:00   3
9:00-10:00  20
10:00-11:00 1
14:00-15:00 14
15:00-16:00 1
16:00-17:00 32
17:00-18:00 10
```

As these are entry's from today, I don't have any entries after 19:00.
Also I don't see an entry from 00:00 - 01:00, 03:00 - 04:00 and several others are missing.
But I do want to show a list with every 24 hour and the result, even if there's nothing.
String thing is the result shows a 0 between 02:00 - 03:00.
I've learned a lot today about mysql, but nothing that solves my issue.

I hope you can learn me something, doesn't have to be code, a direction would be great.

Comment: How you want manage `null` usage times?

Comment: as much as I recommend doing as much as possible in the db, you'd be better off doing a standard `select hour(usage_time), ... group by hour(usage_time)` in the db, then filling in the "holes" in your client-side display logic. Plus, your where clause needs work. you've chained 2 ands with an or, and no bracketing to tell mysql how to do the logic. is it `(a and b) or c`, or is `a and (b or c)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `LEFT JOIN` over `RIGHT JOIN` personally.  That way you can add your `WHERE` criteria in your `JOIN` and it won't constrict your results.  Try this:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(Hour, ':00-', Hour+1, ':00') AS Hours,
     COUNT(`usage_time`) AS `usage` 
FROM 
   (
         SELECT  0 AS Hour
         UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2 UNION ALL SELECT  3
         UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5 UNION ALL SELECT  6
         UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8 UNION ALL SELECT  9
         UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
         UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
         UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18
         UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21
         UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
  )      AS AllHours 
      LEFT JOIN `usage` ON HOUR(`usage_time`) = Hour 
           AND `usage_function` LIKE 'PlayedWholeSong' 
           AND `usage_date` = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) 
GROUP BY Hour
ORDER BY Hour
```

Here is a simplified [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76c2a/1).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for opening my eyes in with JOIN and pointing me to this nice site. I'm going to practice some more now.
Damn, it's a whole lot easier to read with LEFT JOIN :D