# How can I fill missing date-time values for an sql result in php

Tags: php, mysql, linegraph

I have an sql request that returns record counts for every 5 minutes (or 15 minutes).
So I can show that on a line graphic. But this data by itself returns wrong graphic, because some time spans have no records so no date returns for that intervals and this is causes to show a wrong graphic.

Here is my sql code.

```
SELECT
        YEAR(postdate) as Y, MONTH(postdate) as M, DAY(postdate) as D, HOUR(postdate) as H, MINUTE(postdate),
        FLOOR(MINUTE(postdate) / 5) * 5 AS MinIntVal,
        SUM(CASE type WHEN 'ins' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Instagram,
        SUM(CASE type WHEN 'twi' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Twitter,
        SUM(1) as TotalPost

FROM
entries
WHERE
    postdate IS NOT NULL
    AND postdate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
GROUP BY
    YEAR(postdate), MONTH(postdate), DAY(postdate), MinIntVal
ORDER BY D DESC, H DESC, MinIntVal Desc
```

And result is below
[image: wrong graphic]

But the desired / expected result should be looked like below
[image]

So in php how can I add missing 'empty' date values or someone suggested I should add an other table only contains dates, but I have no idea how it should work.

Comment: Whilst you *can* [get MySQL to fill in the blanks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10429660) for you, that's really the wrong way to tackle this problem.  The knowledge that data points should be present for every quarter hour within the queried range exists in your data access layer (PHP), not in the RDBMS; therefore that layer can easily recognise when results are missing and interpret them accordingly—i.e. treat as 0 if (as in this case) that is the correct business logic for such a circumstance.

Comment: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/   is a note on this topic.