# How to store averages per hour in a new table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, average

I have the following table in mySQL, php:

table1:

```
Value1 Timestamp
312    2021-05-25 16:33:15
350    2021-05-25 16:33:25
411    2021-05-25 16:33:35
308    2021-05-25 16:33:45
etc
```

This table stores values in real time, every 10 seconds.

I would like to take the hourly averages of the values in table1 and store them in another table:

table2:

```
Value2 Timestamp
325    2021-05-25 16:59:59
330    2021-05-25 17:59:59
289    2021-05-25 18:59:59
```

I assume that I have to store the previous' hour average
because the current hour's average is still changing.
And that I have to store a value, once per hour.

Comment: Better would be use aggregating query, not another table - but that may depend on circumstances.

Comment: Would grouping your `value1` by hour and showing the average of each group solve your issue? If so, there is a really good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429611/mysql-group-by-hours)

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate to the hour using:

```
select
    cast(date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as timestamp) as hh,
    avg(value1)
from t
group by hh;
```

You can insert into a new table or use `create table as`.